# Will a parent object that is no longer referenced be reclaimed through GC if the parent object itself holds a live reference?

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection, dispose, idisposable

Will a parent object that is no longer referenced be ineligible for collection if it holds a reference to an object that is still alive, like a singleton service that is referenced in other viewmodels?

I've yet to find this explicit situation explained in regards to GC. My inclination is that everythings fine as-is, because ParentViewModel doesn't "own" the service, it will still be reclaimed.

Consider these scenarios..

```
public class MainClass
{
    public SingletonService SingletonService{ get; }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        using (ParentViewModel parentVM as new ParentViewModel(this.SingletonService))
        {
            // Work.
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDiposable
{
    private readonly SingletonService _service;

    public ParentViewModel(SingletonService singleton)
    {
        this._service = _service;
    }
    
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Will my readonly reference to a living singleton prevent the ParentViewModel from being reclaimed?
    }
}
```

Will my readonly reference to a living singleton prevent the ParentViewModel from being reclaimed?

```
public class ParentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDiposable
{

    public SingletonService SingletonService{ get; }
    
    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Do I need to null the SingletonServiceproperty to allow for ParentViewModel to be reclaimed?
        // What if SingletonService has bindings to a view?
    }

    public bool SomeValue
    {
        get => this.SingletonService.OtherValue
    }

}
```

Do I need to null the SingletonService property to allow for ParentViewModel to be reclaimed?

What if SingletonService has bindings to a view?

Would I need to also set SomeValue to null because it uses the service to bind through?

Comment: Consider this: the GC reclaims any object that cannot be reached from a known set of roots: static fields, local variables, and stuff like `GCHandle`. References only flow one way. If no one references your `ParentViewModel`, it's going to be collected, regardless of what it itself is referencing.

Answer (score 1):

GC will reclaim all memory that is inaccessible.

Since the references are uni-directionaly, the singleton (and basically any other objects for that matter) have no idea about the existence of `ParentViewModel` so that will be freed by the GC without having any impact on the program.